# Why does PHP file return "array", but not its contents

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, get

I am tring to send an array to PHP, PHP however, only outputs "array". I have two files:
forms1.php and forms1.js. The PHP if statement never turns true. I have tried without the if statement too.

Thanks for pointing it out in the comments, Yes I call the function, and the alert returns entire forms1.php code.

old title: Why does my php file not see GET["result"]?
// this title is wrong

**forms1.js**

```
var nums = [1,2,3,4];

function postcars() {
    $.ajax({
    type    : 'GET',
    url     : 'forms1.php',
    data    : {"result": nums},
    success: function(resp)
    {
        alert(resp);
    } 
});
}
```

**forms1.php**

```
<?php
if ($_GET["result"] != null){
  $filename = $_GET["result"];
  echo $filename;
}
?>
```

Comment: Why are you comparing to null to begin with? You should be using `isset` or `empty` to check if an external parameter is set/empty.

Comment: What is returned by the AJAX request? Have you checked the console to ensure there's no errors?

Comment: Two parts to debug. And it might make sense to manually enter the expected URL in the browser to see the PHP results. Also error_reporting.

Comment: Also, you can not properly output an array in PHP using echo, that will only get the you the literal word `Array` as result.

Comment: Just to make sure: you do call `postcars()` somewhere?

Comment: @brombeer, yes. I should have made that clear.

Comment: @CBroe, I will take your advice seriously, why is it better to use isset instead of empty or isset?

Comment: Are you sending the ajax request to the same page? And is that ***all*** the content of `forms1.php`?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius yes I am, forms1.js is referenced in forms1.php.

Comment: if you send an ajax request to the same page there are things that you need to do to prevent the entire page source becoming part of the response data

Comment: @brombeer no, not the entire page code, so not php tags and such, I'll edit the comment, and yes. PHP definetly works

Comment: probably you need to post  data with `data    : {"result": JSON.stringify(nums)}`, otherwise the parameter name is not `result` but `result[]`

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius, thanks. I'll google some. If you have some sources however, feel free to post them.

Comment: @ProGu, that's right. It worked. Feel free to post the answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nums` is an array, elements inside might be sent as individual values and the parameter name is `result[]`, make it a single string by using `JSON.stringify`

```
var nums = [1,2,3,4];

function postcars() {
    $.ajax({
    type    : 'GET',
    url     : 'forms1.php',
    data    : {"result": JSON.stringify(nums)},
    success: function(resp)
    {
        alert(resp);
    } 
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I'd normally do would be to test if a particular parameter is in the request ( using `isset()` or `!empty()` ) and then call `ob_clean()` to discard any possible output buffer generated at that stage. Process the request and then terminate the processing completely as it is a different thread. The response then that is set back is **only** what you want to send. This approach with a GET request would cause a regular page loading where there is a querystring, such as `forms1.php?result=banana`, to halt at that stage and display no further content however/.

```
<?php
    if( isset( $_GET['result'] ) ){
        ob_clean();
        $filename = $_GET["result"];
        /* do interesting stuff with variable... */
        
        exit('Hello World! - Send a response');
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>geronimo</title>
        <script src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <script>
            var nums = [1,2,3,4];

            function postcars() {
                $.ajax({
                    type    : 'GET',
                    url     : 'forms1.php',
                    data    : {"result": nums},
                    success: function(resp){
                        alert(resp);
                    } 
                });
            };
            // oops, forgot to call the ajax function
            postcars(); 
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for good programming practices. //oops, forgot to reply to you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You did not call the function `postcars()`;

The JavaScript file should be like this:

```
var nums = [1,2,3,4];

function postcars() {
    $.ajax({
    type    : 'GET',
    url     : 'forms1.php',
    data    : {"result": nums},
    success: function(resp)
    {
        alert(resp);
    } 
});
}

postcars();
```

Comment: I called postcars. Its my fault tho, I didnt make that clear when I first posted the Q.